# Laravel 5.2 - issue with webservices

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, server, laravel-5

Recently I am facing one issue with laravel 5.2 Actually, my project is setup on shared hosting server, I am using larval 5.2 for web services but I can't able to pass token with a header, the same code is working fine with 4.2 And the same code is working fine on any dedicated server, From my first R&D I found that I can't able to pass information in the header if my SERVER ["HTTP_CONNECTION"] is 'Off' once I change it to KeepAlive On everything is working good. Can anyone help me on this. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found solution of my problem :)
Just use below code in your htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

It's Done